# which way is better when using SVG

Tags: reactjs, svg

I am developing a website using React and I have almost 40 SVG, so which way is better to use them

1-`<img src="./name.svg"/>`

2- create component for every one and import them

thank you`

Comment: Component just for an img element? I would probably not create components just of an img elements. It is really opinion based. What would you like?

Comment: Or is it an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new component for each one and import them. That way you can reuse them in other parts of your app as a react component and not an img tag. But in essense, it doesnt really matter